# Application error when deploying website to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

My first time deploying the website I got a long error as shown below.

```
2020-09-25T07:31:36.727714+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-25T07:31:36.730015+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-25T07:31:40.230036+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2020-09-25T07:31:43.021415+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-09-25T07:31:43.061920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-25T07:31:44.106774+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secure-coast-24568.herokuapp.com request_id=3ba32d6b-e60d-4566-8a67-bf06d6957146 fwd="116.88.43.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-25T07:31:44.535220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=secure-coast-24568.herokuapp.com request_id=2e8669b0-19cb-43aa-90c8-1e1770aa3e6a fwd="116.88.43.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-25T07:36:38.651280+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secure-coast-24568.herokuapp.com request_id=0d39c46b-d0d8-4bfb-9516-1c8fae89dce6 fwd="116.88.43.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-25T07:36:39.102621+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=secure-coast-24568.herokuapp.com request_id=9b23f6b1-e2ec-4f12-8b25-cb000a229675 fwd="116.88.43.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-25T07:48:16.835509+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secure-coast-24568.herokuapp.com request_id=956d30e4-a981-48fd-9ec9-2598975d3e1d fwd="116.88.43.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-25T07:48:17.345353+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=secure-coast-24568.herokuapp.com request_id=35947874-9055-4b74-ab76-31c4329e0c72 fwd="116.88.43.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I am not sure what is the cause of the problem but there were many others too getting the same errors which was rectified. Going through what they did to fix the problem I followed the steps but still got the same error. Currently the website is working 100% when used locally and I did multiple tests before I deployed it.

This is my server.js

```js
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = require("./app");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

process.on("uncaughtException", () => {
  process.exit(1);
});

dotenv.config({
  path: "./config.env",
});

const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
  "<PASSWORD>",
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Success");
  });

// Server

const port = process.env.PORT || "3000";

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server started");
});

// Handle all the errors in the async code that wasnt handle

process.on("unhandledRejection", () => {
  server.close(() => {
    process.exit(1);
  });
});
```

My environment variables, e.g. `DATABASE` and `DATABASE_PASSWORD`, are set in a file called `config.env`, which is ignored via my `.gitignore` since it contains sensitive information.

Comment: These errors don't tell us very much. Can you show us your `server.js`?

Comment: @Chris here you go.

Comment: I don't see your "Server started" message in the logs. Are you sure your database credentials are correct? You have a `DATABASE` environment variable, and a `DATABASE_PASSWORD`? Where do they come from? Consider adding more logging output to this script.

Comment: @Chris yeah those information are in stored in the config.env file which is ignored in .gitignore since i wouldnt want sensitive data to be stored in my repo.  Logging output to this script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `config.env` file should indeed be ignored. Sensitive information like your database credentials shouldn't be committed.

However, your application needs those values. On Heroku, the solution is to set [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) that get exposed to your application as environment variables. You can do this with the Heroku CLI, e.g.

```
heroku config:set DATABASE_PASSWORD=12345
```

or via the web dashboard.

Note that in most cases you shouldn't be setting database credentials manually on Heroku. Use a [database addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores) and whatever config vars *it* sets, e.g. the Heroku Postgres service sets a variable called `DATABASE_URL` automatically.